# Grunt: bundle HTML-page into a single HTML-file incl. all dependencies

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs, build-tools

I have a project that just consists of single HTML page, which includes several JavaScript and CSS files (at the moment via `<include>` and `<style>`).
For development including the individual files is quite nice.

**My problem:** for bundling a release, I would like to (automatically) bundle all scripts/css into one *single HTML-file*.
The build process (testing, code formatting, JSDoc generation) is implemented with Grunt.

**Desired solution:** I need a Grunt plugin (or something that can be integrated with Grunt) to "compile" the *single HTML-file* file.

Just for completeness (link to the project repo): https://github.com/dennisguse/TheKarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `grunt-assets-inline`. ([Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-assets-inline))